# What is the command to list all jobs in Apache Aurora scheduler?

Tags: apache-aurora

I have set up an Apache Aurora cluster and managed to schedule hello world tasks.

What command should I use to list/view the tasks in the cluster?

Comment: See Aurora Client Commands reference [page](http://aurora.apache.org/documentation/latest/reference/client-commands/#viewingexamining-jobs).

Answer (score 0):

**Apache Aurora client**

Apache Aurora has a [client](https://aurora.apache.org/documentation/latest/reference/client-commands/). Among other things, it can be used to list jobs running on the cluster:

`aurora job list cluster[/role[/env[/name]]]`

**Example**

For example to list all jobs scheduled in a cluster with say name

> clustertest

this command

> `aurora job list clustertest`

would return the list of jobs:

`clustertest/root/test/python-flask-api`

`clustertest/root/test/rabbitpy`

`clustertest/root/devel/python-hello-world`